# Need RESTLET + JAX-RS + JSON Good example

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jax-rs, jackson, restlet

I'm experimenting the Restlet framework with AppEngine and I try to retrieve a list of Object (ArrayList for instance) to a JSON representation with JAX-rs Resource

For instance a sample User class:

```
 public class User {

    private String lastname;

    private String firstname;

    public User(){};
    public User(String lname,String fname){
        this.firstname = fname;
        this.lastname = lname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
 }
```

I want to retrieve a list of User like this

```
@GET @Path("users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {     
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    users.add(new User("userlastname1", "userfirstname1"));
    users.add(new User("userlastname3", "userfirstname2"));

    return users;
}
```

and I want to get this JSON representation

```
[
    {
        lastname: "userlastname1",
        firstname: "userfirstname1"
    },
    {
        lastname: "userlastname2",
        firstname: "userfirstname2"
    }
]
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

The Restlet documentation mentioned the serialization proccess is automated, yes it's the case for only one Object like "User"

```
new User("userlastname1", "userfirstname1")
```

return me the good JSON representation

```
{
    lastname: "userlastname1",
    firstname: "userfirstname1" 
}
```

If some one can give me some explanation/sample code/idea about that. much appreciated

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I actually just figured this out for myself using the Java EE edition of Restlet. Not sure if this module is available for the GAE sandbox, but I just added the Restlet extension for Jackson as a dependency and it worked like a charm.

If you are using Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>  
    <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>  
    <version>2.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Path("/users")
public interface IUserRoutes
{
    @GET
    Response getUsers();
}


@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserRoutesImpl implements IUserRoutes
{
    public Response getUsers()
    {
        return new UserResponse().getUsers();
    }
}


public class UserResponse
{
    public Response getUser()
    {
        List<Users> users = new UserModel().getUsers();
        return Response.ok(users).build();
    }
}
```

Your User object should be a POJO.

```
public class User
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstname()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastname()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
    //etc 
}
```